# Can I add content before post content without using the_content filter

Tags: wordpress

I am adding filter to add embed before post content, but don't want add to other places where called apply_filters("the_content").

So i need add embed before(after) post content without "the_content" filter hook.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'embed_on_post');
```

Comment: you say you don't want to add the filter on "other places", but it is not clear where you actually want the filter to be applied

Comment: For example if any one added filter to title, i need filter only for post content. Do You know any method to add embed before post content without 'the_content' filter?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to filter only a certain type or such, you can add your verification inside your filter function:

source: [wordpress documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content)

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_function' ); 

function my_function( $content ) {
    //for a single post
    if (is_singular('post')) {
        /* do whant you want */
    }

    //or also (works for posts except attachments and pages)
    if (is_single()){

    }

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: But it can work for title also, if in singular page added 'the_content' filter to title. I need to determine if content really content of post

Comment: `the_content` is not meant to be applied to a title, if you do this, it is not the filter's fault!! however, if you really want to avoid this kind o mistake to be done, the only way i see to do it is to retreive the whole post object from its id and compare the content to what you receive. However, this might not work if something already modified (even slightly) the content before you receive it in the filter. Might be more hazardous than to rely on the filter to be used at right places. That is also a bit overkill imo